# Why is this code snippet giving an error?

Tags: java

```
    Set set=new TreeSet();

    set.add(2);
    set.add(1);
    set.add("3");
    System.out.println(set);
```

Set is a `Collection` and it is not homogeneous so it should take any value (Both `Integer` and `String`)

Comment: Any particular error?  During compilation or execution?  Where does the error occur?

Comment: You're trying to compare an `Integer` with a `String` - how do you expect that comparison to work?

Answer (score 5):

`TreeSet` stores its values in order - which means they have to be comparable with each other. You can't compare an `Integer` with a `String`, so you get an exception at execution time.

If you really want to be able to do this, you could provide your own custom `Comparator` to the constructor of the `TreeSet`, implementing what ever comparison logic you want.